# Ajax request produces internal server error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization

I am using ace editor to enable code editing on browser. Now there is a save feature when user clicks it I send the code from the editor back to the server using ajax request. But I am getting a Internal Service Error on checking browser's console.

Ajax Client code

```
$('#save-button').click(function () {

            $.post('/CodeEditor/SaveFile',
            {
                'file': $('#current-file').val(),
                'content': editor.getValue()
            }, function () {

            },
            'JSON');
});
```

Ajax Server Code

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveFile(string file, string content)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

Following are the contents of file that I am submitting via Ajax in content parameter

```
@model IList<ShopifyHome.Models.TemplatePartial>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>ModifyTemplate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/aciTree    /css/aciTree.css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/aciTree/css/demo.css" media="all" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    @*<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/aciTree/js/jquery.min.js"></script>*@
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/aciTree/js/jquery.aciPlugin.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/aciTree/js/jquery.aciTree.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/aciTree/js/jquery.aciTree.selectable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/aciTree/js/jquery.aciTree.checkbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Content/aciTree/js/jquery.aciTree.radio.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #frame-div
    {

        }

    #style-div
    {
        width:250px;
        float:right;
        height:50%;
        margin: auto auto; ...
```

The request does go through and is received on server side when contents of file are simple like

```
This is text
```

Comment: What specific error do you receive?

Comment: I get Internal Server Error on the client side when I have complicated stuff written in the editor like the code you see above.
But everything works fine when some simple string such as "Hello World" is written the editor.
Actually I do know there is something wrong with the deserialization (done on server) of the JSON (submitted by client)

Comment: try changing your post with an ajax call.  see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22228758/jquery-trigger-for-submit-form-results-infinite-loop/22273572?noredirect=1#comment33866458_22273572

Comment: Still same problem with following code
    `$.ajax({type: 'POST',url: '/CodeEditor/SaveFile',
data: {
'file': $('#current-file').val(),
'content': editor.getValue()
},
dataType: 'json',
cache: false,
success: function (data) { },
async: true,
error: function (erro) {
console.log(erro);
}
});`

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work. Had to encode the html and then decode it on server-side.

Client code

```
$.post('/CodeEditor/SaveFile',
{
    'file': $('#current-file').val(),
    'content': encodeURIComponent(editor.getValue())
},
function () {
},
"JSON");
```

Server code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveFile(string file, string content)
{
    content = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(content);
}
```